# Accessing static member field causes Null pointer exception

Tags: java, oop

Is there something wrong with the way I'm accessing the static field 'cache' from the config loader class? FYI, `CacheEngine` is an interface that implements a cache client for memcached.

```
public class Test {
     ...
     getCache(){
       ...
       try{
        cacheData =  ConfigLoader.cache.get(key); // Accessing the static 'cache' memeber returns Null Pointer Exception  
        ...
       }
     }
}

//ConfigLoader Class
public class ConfigLoader{
    public static CacheEngine cache;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well... make sure ConfigLoader.cache is initialized before you access it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's bad design, but the way you access it, is correct. Your problem is, that `cache` isn't initialized. You need to do so somewhere:

```
public static CacheEngine cache = new CacheEngine(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have not intialised the `static CacherEngine cache;`

To intialise add the following code in `static` constructor in the `ConfigLoader class`:

```
static{
cache=new CacheEngine(...);}
```

This is an alternative way, but it is not recommended.Add this in your declarations:
`public static CacheEngine cache=new CacheEngine`

Answer (score 1):

Do before you access cache

```
if (cache==null) cache = new CacheEngine(...);
```

Just initialize it before you access it. Also in a good OOP design, you'd make a static init method.